What happens to the fundamental group of a topological space as you add more open sets in the topology?
For a given topological space $X$, as we increase the number of open sets then it becomes more difficult for a function to be continous when it's codomain is $X$, as there preimage of open set must be open set for many more open sets.
So, I guess in some sense the fundamental group should get smaller.
But, can we make the exact dependence of the fundamental group on the choice of topology a bit more precise? It would be even good if I would be suggested a paper which studies how the choice of topology influences the fundamental group.

Interesting question: I don't have an answer, but note that it may also become more difficult to find homotopies, so your argument that the fundamental group will become smaller may not work.

In fact, since the indiscrete topology on any (non-empty) set is simply connected, adding open sets can cause an arbitrary rise in complexity of the fundamental group.

I do not think that there are usable results. Adding open sets produces completely new toplogical spaces with different fundamental groups.

I guess in some sense the fundamental group should get smaller.

This is in general not true. Here are some examples.

Given a group  $G$, we can construct a space $X$ such that $\pi_1(X) =  G$. Let $X'$ be the space having the same underlying set as $X$ and having the trivial topology. Then $\pi_1(X') = 0$, but the space $X$ which is obtained from $X'$ by adding open sets has a bigger fundamental group.

Let $p : [0,1) \to S^1, p(t) = e^{2\pi it}$. The map $p$ is a continuous bijection, thus we can add open sets to $S^1$ (which gives a space $\bar S^1$) such that $p : [0,1) \to  \bar S^1$ becomes a homeomorphism. We have $\pi_1(S^1) =\mathbb Z$ and $\pi_1(\bar S^1) = 0$. In that case the fundamental group got smaller.


